# C# Graphics.DrawImage() transparent png background

Tags: c#, linux, image, draw, imaging

I'm developing an image editor application using C# with the help of the `System.Drawing.Graphics` class. The app must be able to operate on Windows and Linux as well.

The scenario is simple, I have a background image (jpeg, 24bpp, **not** progressive), and I have to draw transparent png images onto it. I'm using the following pattern (with other coordinates and more images):

```
Bitmap backgroundJpg = new Bitmap("bg.jpg");
Bitmap transparentPng = new Bitmap("transp.png");

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(backgroundJpg))
{
    g.DrawImage(transparentPng, new Point(0, 0));
}

backgroundJpg.Save("test.jpg");
```

On **Windows**, the result of this process is OK.
On **Linux**, it looks like the png images are not being handled correctly, it looks like they are not "transparent well" when they are being drawn by the `Graphics` instance. *(Edit: I've checked, they are transparent, but not the way as on Windows.)*

*Edit: I'm interested in alternative solutions as well, if it runs both on Windows and Linux.*

*Edit 2: It looks like **the transparency is bad only if the transparent image has background** behind it. If it is being drawn on a blank `Format32bppArgb` image, it is OK.*

---

Additional information:

Maybe I'm missing some configuration options to force it to be transparent during the drawing process, or there is something to be configured on the Linux itself.

**Linux Configuration:** *(if it helps)*
A BeagleBone Black device with
- Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy).
- Mono:
    - JIT compiler: 4.0.5
    - Architecture: armel, vfp+hard
    - GC: sgen

Any help would be appreciated, and feel free to ask if any other details needed. Thanks!

*Note: on the following images, the red "X" is part of the black background, and the blue images are the transparent pngs.*

**Windows 8.1 result:**
[image: Windows 8.1 result]

**Linux Debian result:**
[image: Linux Debian result]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new image with 32bpp ARGB, drawing the JPEG on that and then the PNGs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to get the result that way, but I've got the same result as above. This way, if I do not draw the jpg background, just the png ones, the transparency is good.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: The `mono --version` result's first line: *Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.5 (Stable 4.0.5.1/1d8d582 Thu Nov 12 12:22:41 UTC 2015)*. If you'd need more details about it, please tell me how/where can I acquire those.